# ¿ Cuál es la diferencia entre self y super(Clase, self)?

Tags: python

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    self
    super(ContactForm, self)
```

Aca self y super(ContactForm, self) es lo mismo o ¿cual es la diferencia ?

Comment: Si no me equivoco esta pregunta se realizo anteriormente....

Answer (score 9):

Para las clases, en python, `self` hace referencia a una instancia de la clase. Recuerda que tu estas creando una clase, pero para que esa clase pueda llegar a ser un objeto necesita ser *instanciada*, es lo que usualmente ves como:

```
class Foo(object):  # aqui creamos la clase
  property_a = 1
  pass

a = Foo()  # aqui la instanciamos
```

Entonces, sabemos que una vez instanciada la clase `Foo`, podemos acceder desde `a` a su atributo `property_a`, de la siguiente manera:

```
>>> a.property_a
>>> 1
```

Dentro de la clase, en un método para ser mas específico, podemos acceder a `self`, porque desde la clase en sí, no sabemos como se llamará la instancia, es decir, tu accedes a `a.property_a` porque tu declaraste a `a`, pero la clase no sabe que se llama `a` o quizas podria llamarse `b`, entonces por eso para hacer referencia a su propia instancia, existe `self`, de modo que podríamos hacer algo así:

```
class Foo:
   property_a = 1

   def method(self):  # por eso ves que siempre el primer parametro de un metodo es self.
      print(self.property_a)  # lo mismo que en ejemplo anterior a.property_a

>>> a = Foo()
>>> a.method()  # a pesar que el metodo require un argumento llamado self, la clase la pasa por nosotros.
>>> 1
```

Esto quiere decir, que hacer esto es igualmente válido:

```
>>> Foo.method(a)  # ya que como self es una instancia, estas pasando el parametro de forma manual.
```

Habiendo explicado la parte de `self`, viene la parte de `super`.

Por cierto, en python 3, puedes acceder solo como `super()`, y si estas en python 2, te recomendaria usar `super(self.__class__, self)`.

Super, se utiliza cuando estas haciendo programación orientada a objetos y usas herencia, para las clases que son herencia de otras clases, en muchas ocaciones, te encontraras con que debes añadir código a métodos ya existentes, para añadir funcionalidad a tu código, o lo que se conoce como 'sobrescribir', te explico con un ejemplo.

```
class Animal:
   def __init__(self, ojos, bocas):
      self.ojos = ojos
      self.bocas = bocas

class Humano(Animal):  # aplicamos la herencia
   def __init__(self, ojos, bocas, brazos, piernas):
      self.ojos = ojos
      self.bocas = bocas
      self.brazos = brazos
      self.piernas = piernas
```

De esta forma, me tocó sobrescribir todos los atributos de animal solo por que quise añadir funcionalidad, aquí no hay problema, porque es algo corto, puedo hacerlo simple, pero en ocaciones serán muchas lineas, entonces me ayudo de `super()` de esta forma:

```
# con la misma clase Animal
class Humano(Animal):
   def __init__(self, ojos, bocas, brazos, piernas):
      super().__init__(ojos, bocas)
      self.brazos = brazos
      self.piernas = piernas
```

Ya si miras en este ejemplo, lo que se hizo fue llamar al `padre` de humano, en este caso es Animal, y así inicializarlo, para no perder lo que el ya hacia con su código. De esta forma, es igualmente válido luego crear una instancia y ver su atributo ojos.

```
>>> a = Humano(ojos=2, bocas=1, brazos=2, piernas=2)
>>> a.ojos
>>> 2
>>> a.bocas
>>> 1
```

Todo lo hizo el `super()` por nosotros...

**Recuerda:** en python 2 debes usar `super(self.__class__, self)`

Espero haberte ayudado, cualquier duda pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

**"self"** en sí *NO es NADA*. Por *convenio*, se da el nombre de `self` al primer argumento que reciben los métodos de una clase y que corresponde con una instancia, que puede ser o no instancia de la clase en cuestión. Puedes usar cualquier otro nombre.

Para *métodos de clase*, en lugar de una instancia se recibe una clase como primer argumento. Con los *métodos estáticos*, no se recibe ningún argumento adicional.

Cada instancia tiene asociada una jerarquía de clases. La función `super()` busca en este orden jeráquico la clase superior a partir de una clase dada y delega en ella. Es de este modo como es posible especializar un método heredado.

Por ejemplo:

```
super(ContactForm, self)
```

Busca en la jerarquía de clases asociada a `self` aquella clase que esté por encima de `ContactForm`. Lo esperable es que sea `forms.Form`, que es la clase padre de `ContactForm`.

Pero no siempre es así, sobre todo si hay herencia múltiple:

```
class A:
    def say(self): print("class A")

class B(A):
    def say(self): print("class B")

class C(A):
    def say(self): print("class C")

class D(B,C):
    def say(self): print("class D")

x = D()
super(B, x).say()  # --> class C
```

Aunque `C` no es una clase superior a `B`, en el orden de búsqueda figura después de buscar en `B`. Esta ordenación de clases se conoce como algoritmo **MRO** y es la que hace funcionar la herencia múltiple.

Se puede comprobar esta ordenación con el atributo `__mro__`:

```
>>> D.__mro__
(__main__.D, __main__.B, __main__.C, __main__.A, object)
```