# Hacer que cambie QLabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

Estoy practicando con `PyQt` y he hecho un ejercicio que imprime en consola cual botón presione, luego quise cambiarlo para que aparezca en un `QLabel`, pro me da un error

> File "llamar.pyw", line 30, in b1_clicked
>       self.txt1.setText("Presionaste el Primer Boton") NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Este es el código:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def window() :
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   win = QDialog()
   #label
   txt1 = QLabel(win)
   txt1.setGeometry(30,10,150,30)
   txt1.setText("Presione un Boton...")

   #primer boton
   b1 = QPushButton(win)
   b1.setText("Button1")
   b1.move(70,50)
   b1.clicked.connect(b1_clicked)
   #segundo boton
   b2 = QPushButton(win)
   b2.setText("Button2")
   b2.move(70,70)
   QObject.connect(b2,SIGNAL("clicked() "),b2_clicked)

   win.setGeometry(100,100,300,200)
   win.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
   win.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_() )

def b1_clicked() :
   txt1.setText("Presionaste el Primer Boton")

def b2_clicked() :
   txt1.setText("Presionaste el Segundo Boton")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tu objeto `tex1` es una variable local, perteneciente a tu función `window`, que solo puede ser accedida desde dicha función. Para que tus funciones `b1_clicked` y `b2_clicked` puedan acceder a este objeto y usar sus métodos debes hacerlo accesible a estas funciones. Hay varias opciones, una de ellas es usar variables globales (normalmente mejor evitarlas), la otra opción es pasarles a estas dos funciones como argumento el objeto `tex1` (usando funciones `lambda` o `functools.partial`):

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

def window() :
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   win = QDialog()
   #label
   txt1 = QLabel(win)
   txt1.setGeometry(30,10,150,30)
   txt1.setText("Presione un Boton...")

   #primer boton
   b1 = QPushButton(win)
   b1.setText("Button1")
   b1.move(70,50)
   b1.clicked.connect(partial(b1_clicked,  txt1))
   #segundo boton
   b2 = QPushButton(win)
   b2.setText("Button2")
   b2.move(70,70)
   b2.clicked.connect(partial(b2_clicked,  txt1))

   win.setGeometry(100,100,300,200)
   win.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
   win.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_() )

def b1_clicked(widget) :
   widget.setText("Presionaste el Primer Boton")

def b2_clicked(widget) :
   widget.setText("Presionaste el Segundo Boton")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

Aunque funcione, usar programación estructurada complica mucho la vida en cuanto la app es medianamente compleja. Usar programcaión orinetada a objetos es en principio lo ideal, y en muchos casos, casi imprescindible si no queremos complicarnos la vida sin necesidad.

Debes evitar siempre (solo en casos muy concretos deberían ser usados) los import de la forma `from modulo import*`. Dificulta la legibilidad del código, pobla el espacio de nombres sin necesidad y abre la posibilidad de que se ocasionen colisiones entre módulos importados o con identificadores del propio módulo.

Usando POO y teniendo lo anterior en cuenta, el código podría ser así:

```
# Importamos modulos necesarios
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui 


# Creamos nuestra clase Window que en este caso hereda de QtDialog   
class Window(QtGui.QDialog):

    # Metodo especiar __init__, inicializador que es ejecutado nada mas instanciar
    def __init__(self,  parent = None):

        # usamos super para llamar al __init__ de la clase padre
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.setGeometry(100,100,300,200)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt")

        #label
        self.txt1 = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.txt1.setGeometry(30,10,150,30)
        self.txt1.setText("Presione un Boton...")
        self.txt1.adjustSize()
        #primer boton
        self.b1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.b1.setText("Button1")
        self.b1.move(70,50)
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.b1_clicked)
        #segundo boton
        self.b2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.b2.setText("Button2")
        self.b2.move(70,80)
        self.b2.clicked.connect(self.b2_clicked)
        self.show()

    def b1_clicked(self) :
        self.txt1.setText("Presionaste el Primer Boton")
        self.txt1.adjustSize() 

    def b2_clicked(self) :
        self.txt1.setText("Presionaste el Segundo Boton")
        self.txt1.adjustSize() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`self` hace referencia a la instancia de la clase, en nuestro caso sera una instancia de nuestra clase `Window`, que al heredar de `QtDialog` hereda todos sus métodos y atributo.

Más información sobre `self` y `super`:

[¿ Cuál es la diferencia entre self y super(Clase, self)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48520/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-self-y-superclase-self)

Y sobre`__init__`:

[Duda con clases. ¿Para que sirve __init__?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79502/duda-con-clases-para-que-sirve-init)

Comment: Gracias de nuevo. en verdad estoy aplicando un poco la estructurada para ir entendiendo mas el python, y pyqt que no se me esta haciendo facil. ya entiendo muchos conceptos pero aun me falta. Gracias por tu ayuda y concejos.

Comment: @MarcoSalazar realmente para aprender empezar por la estructurada antes de pasar a POO es el camino correcto en mi opinión, lenguajes como Python o C++ permiten esto al se multiparadigma. Tal vez empezar directamente con Qt se te haga un poco mas duro pero paso a paso se llega lejos... Un saludo.